# Loading Json into uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to load json into a uitableview. I have worked with json before but never used it with a tableview. I keep getting this error: -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I'm pretty sure it is because in the numberOfRowsInSection method im returning the count of the array. Please let me know how to fix this or if I am missing something and not seeing it.

Here is he code:
.h file

```
    @interface HistoryViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,                  UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *jsonData;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{       
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Json url"]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self ];


[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[responseData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *response = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

jsonData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return  jsonData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                         reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


cell.textLabel.text = [jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What I'm guessing is that `[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]` is actually returning a number, and not an array like your code is expecting. Could you place a line with `NSLog(@"Key: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"])` or something like that and tell us what that returns? That would allow us to ascertain what data type is at that dictionary key.

Comment: You should use AFNetwork + JSONKit, and use a AFJsonRequestOperation, it's much simpler !

Comment: @Paul I inserted the NSLog and it is returning the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I notice that your array is never initialized until the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method is run. The delegate methods for your data table are likely running before `connectionDidFinishLoading`, so you should initialize your `jsonData` array in `viewDidLoad` instead of `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

You can keep your `connectionDidFinishLoading` calls the same, but make sure you call `reloadData` on your data table at the end of the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method to fill out your data table with the downloaded data.